# ValueError('Cannot invoke RPC: Channel closed!') when multiple process are launched together

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-pubsub

I get this error when I launch, from zero, more than 4 process in sync:

```
{
  "insertId": "61a4a4920009771002b74809",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "asctime": "2021-11-29 09:59:46,620",
    "message": "Exception in callback <bound method ResumableBidiRpc._on_call_done of <google.api_core.bidi.ResumableBidiRpc object at 0x3eb1636b2cd0>>: ValueError('Cannot invoke RPC: Channel closed!')",
    "funcName": "handle_event",
    "lineno": 183,
    "filename": "_channel.py"
  }
```

This is the pub-sub schema:
[pub-sub-schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrIXw.png)

The error seems to happen at step 9 or 10.
The actual code is:

```
            future = publisher.publish(
            topic_path,
            encoded_message,
            msg_attribute=message_key
        )


        future.add_done_callback(
            callback=lambda f:
            logging.info(...)
        )

        subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
        subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(
            PROJECT_ID,
            "..."
        )

        streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(
            subscription_path,
            callback=aggregator_callback_handler.handle_message
        )
        aggregator_callback_handler.callback = streaming_pull_future


        wait_result(
            timeout=300,
            pratica=...,
            f_check_res_condition=lambda: aggregator_callback_handler.response is not None
        )

        streaming_pull_future.cancel()
        subscriber.close()
```

The module `aggregator_callback_handler` handles .nack and .ack.

The error is returned for some seconds, then the VMs on which the services are hosted scales and the error stops. Same if, instead of launching the processes all together, I scale them manually launching them one by one and leaving some sleep in-between.

I've already checked the timeouts and put the subscriber outside of context manager, but those solutions doesn't work.

Any idea on how to handle this?